# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview:28.3.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-xml

I keep getting this error even I passed this to the build.gradle(project) :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no version `28.3.1` and there will never be. you have to change the dependency to `28.0.0`:

```
implementation "com.android.support:cardview:28.0.0"
```

Comment: @dridinho one can look up these version numbers: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/cardview-v7 & https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.cardview/cardview (where `28.0.0` is the same as `1.0.0`, just below another name-space). that's why using `androidx` already might make sense: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use direct `google()` in repositories

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

there is no version 28.3.1 and there will never be. you have to change the dependency to 28.0.0:

So, Please check these as well

```
implementation "com.android.support:cardview:28.0.0"
```

in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

in project level `build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

Sync the Gradle and then if not fixed

Go to Menu -> File -> click on `Invalidate Crashes / Restart...`